# How can you create a new value using jQuery UI combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, combobox

I've just added the jQuery UI combobox to a page. It seems it restricts selections to only those passed in (or present in the select list). What I wanted to do was to have it so that if the user enters a value that isn't in the select list it sends the data off to the server (on the post) and creates one. I can't see any options to disable 'validation'. How would I go about adding this functionality?

--EDIT--

I've added the code in to get the autocomplete working with a button appended. However this isn't working when calling an Ajax method. The Ajax method is correctly returning json (a list of colours) but when I start typing 'Re' in the hope it'll filter down items that contain Red, it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
var $colInput = $("#Colour").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/stockitems/colours",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { id: null },
                success: function (data) {
                    var arr = [];
                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        arr.push(val.Title);
                    });
                    response(arr);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 0
    }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

    $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
        .attr("tabIndex", -1)
        .attr("title", "Show All Items")
        .insertAfter($colInput)
        .button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        })
        .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
        .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
        .click(function () {
            // close if already visible                         
            if ($colInput.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                $colInput.autocomplete("close");
                return;
            }
            $(this).blur();
            $colInput.autocomplete("search", "");
            $colInput.focus();
        });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The combobox demo uses an underlying `select` element as the backing store for the autocomplete widget. I would not recommend this for a form in which you allow the user to input whatever they want.

However, you can emulate the combobox effect yourself without too much trouble:

```
var $input = $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0
}).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

$("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")                     
    .attr("tabIndex", -1)                     
    .attr("title", "Show All Items")                     
    .insertAfter($input)                     
    .button({                         
        icons: {                             
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"                         
        },                         
        text: false                     
    })                     
    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")                     
    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")                   
    .click(function() {                         
        // close if already visible                         
        if ($input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
             $input.autocomplete( "close" );
             return;                         
        }                                              
        $(this).blur();                                                 
        $input.autocomplete("search", "" );                         
        $input.focus();                     
    });
```

Basically, this is the default behavior of the autocomplete widget, plus a button that will drop down all the options.

This way, the backing field is an `input` element, and you can take the user's input upon form submission and add it to the source for next time.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/CDYBk/1/

Comment: Struggling here with doing an Ajax call. I got your example with some local data working but when I call an Ajax result and pass an array back in the response the items aren't filtering down. I'll add my code in a reply below.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I edited to include my code above. Hope you can throw some light on this, I've spent about an hour and a half trying to get it filtering.

Comment: Ignore me. Got it working. Will post my code later, realised it was polling back to my controller on each character input rather than dealing with cached (local) result - der! :)

Comment: @lloydphillips: Awesome! Glad you got it.

Comment: what if I want to append new items on run-time?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just grab the input value with something like $(...).parentNode.children[1].children[0].value if you don't feel like messing with widgets.  Then you could always add a select option if you wanted.

Comment: a bit late to the party there dude, I asked this question 5 years ago and got an answer back then 
:)